# How to get latest photos where my friends are tagged? v2.1 GraphApi

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

To get the latest photos of my friends (with Graph Api v.2.1, NO FQL) I use the following:

```
me/home/?fields=story,object_id,from,type&filter=app_2305272732&since=1407507775
```

This works, but only shows the photos that they have uploaded or updated.

**How I can get the photo (my friend is tagged) but is not the owner of the picture?**

I can see that kind of pictures with this query type:

```
me/friends/?fields=id,name,photos.limit(2){created_time,updated_time,from,id,name,tags}&date_format=U&limit=15&since=1407507775
```

But it's complicated. When there is a lot of information, the query is slow and does not return results. Lowering the limits and make multiple requests is not an acceptable solution.